# Obtaining information about current playing file, regardless of used player

Tags: android

Is it possible to obtain information about the currently playing file (mp3, flac, doesn't matter), regardless of which player is playing it? I need information that these files provide, like album name, song name etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no such api in the android sdk to detect that.